# Machine stuck at POST 33h when memory modules installed as dual-channel

Tags: memory, post, amd-ryzen, dual-channel

I just setup a new machine with the following (relevant) configuration:

- CPU: Ryzen 9 3900X
- MB: ASRockRack X470D4U (I aimed for its IPMI functionality - turned out to be super useful)
- Memory: 2 pieces of Asgard 32 GB DDR4 3000

  - running at D4 2400 as seem from BIOS
  - [Example Amazon link](https://www.amazon.ca/Asgard-2x16GB-3200Mhz-PC4-25600-Desktop/dp/B083Z6CSB3): It's of the same series and appearance, but mine are 32 GB for each module

The MB is nice enough to be equipped with a two-digit 7-segment display showing POST codes.

#### The issue

The MB has 4 memory slots, marked as A1, A2, B1, B2 respectively.

- When I install a single DIMM module into any of the slots, the system operates normally.
- When I install both modules into A1 and A2, the system operates normally.
- When I install both modules into B1 and B2, the system operates normally.

I want dual-channel memory setup, however:

- When I install both modules into A1 and B1, it gets stuck at POST code 33h.
- When I install both modules into A2 and B2, it gets stuck at POST code 33h.
- When I install both modules into A1 and B2, it gets stuck at POST code 33h.
- When I install both modules into A2 and B1, it gets stuck at POST code 33h.

#### What I've tried

According to ASRockRack's manual (`ftp://asrockchina.com.cn/Manual/X470D4U.pdf`) for this MB, the code 33h stands for `PEI_CPU_CACHE_INIT`. Unfortunately, it doesn't make a good Google keyword.

Several results from a search of `ryzen 3 dual-channel won't boot` suggested issues with the MB, so I downloaded BIOS version 3.10, 3.20 and 3.30 and tried them one-by-one, but none of those BIOS made any observable difference. I didn't dare trying older BIOS because the changelog for 3.10 says "Support Ryzen 7nm CPU".

I even tried BIOS 3.37, which is listed as beta, but it doesn't even POST with dual-channel at all. This BIOS also runs perfectly with single-channel DIMM setup.

---

The machine is currently running well with single-channel RAM setup (both modules installed).

I want to know how I can diagnose further and possibly resolve this strange issue.

Comment: Is your [BIOS](https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=X470D4U#Download) up-to-date? Looks like most recent version is 3.30

Comment: @SamForbis Yes it is. I also tried BIOS 3.10 and 3.20 - none of them made a difference.